# Display uploaded image works in Windows but not in Linux

Tags: php, laravel

This code works perfectly and saves the image properly:

```
if(request()->file("avatar_upload")) {
    $file = request()->file("avatar_upload");
    $ext = $file->guessClientExtension();
    if($ext == "jpg" || $ext == "jpeg" || $ext == "png"){
        $file->storeAs('public/avatars/' . Auth::user()->id , "avatar.jpg");
    }
}
```

Now to display it I use this, which works in Windows but not in Linux:

```
@if(File::exists('/storage/avatars/'.Auth::user()->id))
    <div class="image-upload">
        <label for="avatar_upload">
            <img src="{{asset('/storage/avatars/'.Auth::user()->id)."/avatar.jpg"}}"/>
        </label>
        <input id="avatar_upload" name="avatar_upload" type="file"/>
    </div>
@else
    <div class="image-upload">
        <label for="avatar_upload">
            <img src="/assets/admin/img/noimage.png"/>
        </label>
        <input id="avatar_upload" name="avatar_upload" type="file"/>
    </div>
@endif
```

This always displays noimage.png in Linux, while it retrieves and displays the image Windows.

Any idea why?

Comment: Do you have any errors?

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos Nope, it just won't display the image on linux.

Comment: Do you mean PHP on windows vs linux or a browser?

Comment: @nerdlyist I migrated a laravel project from windows to linux.

Comment: You need to search you codebase then for erroneous `\\` then. It could be anywhere. I would watch your browsers inspector network tab and find failing urls

Comment: Fix the quotes here: `."/avatar.jpg"}}"/> `

Comment: Are you create folder permission for "storage/avatars" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already created folder permission for "`storage/avatars`" and got same issue then:

I think your code need to update like:

```
@if(File::exists('/storage/avatars/'.Auth::user()->id.'/avatar.jpg'))
   <div class="image-upload">
       <label for="avatar_upload">
           <img src="{{asset('/storage/avatars/'.Auth::user()->id).'/avatar.jpg'}}"/>
       </label>
       <input id="avatar_upload" name="avatar_upload" type="file"/>
   </div>
@else
   <div class="image-upload">
       <label for="avatar_upload">
           <img src="/assets/admin/img/noimage.png"/>
       </label>
       <input id="avatar_upload" name="avatar_upload" type="file"/>
   </div>
@endif
```

Hope this work for you!

Comment: upvoted because I forgot to add '/avatar.jpg' at the end, but it didn't solve he problem. I solved it by deleting the / at the beginning of the link ('storage/avatars/'.Auth::user()->id.'/avatar.jpg')